# How to use a pattern on an input[type="number"]?

Tags: html, css, validation, input

I want the default value to be 0 and recolor the input if it's more than 0, using `:valid`. Am I doing something wrong? Is Google Chrome wrong? Or the HTML5 specification? I want to solve this without JS.

```css
:valid {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<p>This should not be green, but it is:</p>
<input max="100" min="0" pattern="^[1-9]\d*$" type="number" value="0" />

<p>Works perfectly, if the type is changed to text:</p>
<input pattern="^[1-9]\d*$" type="text" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 10):

[Citing MDN on the `pattern` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern) (highlighting added):

> pattern
>
> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. 
>   The pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset. Use the
>   title attribute to describe the pattern to help the user. **This
>   attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text,
>   search, tel, url or email; otherwise it is ignored.** The regular
>   expression language is the same as JavaScript's. The pattern is not
>   surrounded by forward slashes.

Interestingly I can't find any mentioning of that in both [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute) and [WhatWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-input-pattern) standards.

Comment: Neither do I, so I see no reason for number inputs to be impossibble to be validated this way. I want to be able to use a pattern for other reasons as well, like checking if the number is odd or even etc. Since the browser doesn't work as it's advised in the spec, I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: The WHATWG spec has a non-normative table that summarizes which attributes apply to which input types. The table shows that `number` is *not* among the input types to which the `pattern` attribute applies. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#concept-input-apply

Comment: Also, the spec states “The subsections that define each type also clearly define in normative "bookkeeping" sections which of these feature apply, and which do not apply, to each type.” Under the **bookkeeping** section in [Number State](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#number-state-(type=number)), it lists `pattern` as one of the attributes that does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

I see that if you give the minimum value of 1, the color is not green for 0. The color changes to green when you enter 1. I think that is what you are expecting, right?

Basically, you can use min and max values for validation purpose. I don't think you need pattern for this.

```
<input max="100" min="1" type="number" value="0" />
```

There is one limitation here. If you leave the field empty, it is still green!

Comment: Not only does OP not *need* `pattern`, but pattern is actually *forbidden* on number type inputs. It states so in [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#concept-input-apply). And for your empty field limitation, simply add the `required` attribute!