# Format number in an HTML5 input tag

Tags: html

This is my input

```
<input type="number" id="inputNumbers" step="0.01" ></input>
```

Is it possible to only allow users to enter numbers that match the pattern '0.00', like the way I declare it in the step attribute, without using JavaScript?

Example: If the user types '1.23' and then tries to enter a new number, decimal or comma it can't and the number stays at '1.23'.

If there's not a way to match the step attribute, Is it possible to only allow one decimal in the number?

Comment: you can use
<input type="number" name="amount" pattern="\d\.\d{2}" title="amount code">

Comment: Match the patern? ever tried regex?

Comment: @SheikhJames thx, but it didn't work..

Comment: @Ctc The regex I've tested didn't get me the result of '0.00'-pattern..Don't know how to create a regex for that..Please share if you know.

Comment: I thought you tried, okay, will give it a shot!

Comment: I recall that jQuery has ways to backspace a wrong character, are you allowed to use JS?

Comment: @Ctc I would love to have a solution in pure HTML5..but a JavaScript/jQuery solution is better then no solution :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a pattern on an input\[type="number"\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411753/how-to-use-a-pattern-on-an-inputtype-number)

Answer (score 7):

I think you can try something like this:

```
input type="number" name="number" pattern="([0-9]{1,3}).([0-9]{1,3})" title="Must contain a decimal number">
```

see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

Added Plunkr:
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ivkPN5n8oTBs2PNlBeS6?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't work..I can for example add 1.444.44,,,,,.,..,,.4545,.

Comment: Well, for me it works, if i try to add a second decimal point i get the message. Maybe your browser doesnt support it.?!

Comment: I've tested it in Chrome v51.0.2704.103 and Firefox DE 48.0a2

Comment: Could you add a plunkr?

Comment: @MarcusH added plunkr which is working for me as well

Comment: the `.` should be `\.`, as `.` will match any character.

Comment: It looks like `pattern` isn't supposed to necessarily work with `number` input types: [Mozilla developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#pattern_validation).  If it does work, it may not be stable long-term.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using javascript with corner case handling using toLocaleString()

```
function getChange(){
  // 48 - 57 (0-9)
  var str1 = valueRef.value;
  if((str1[str1.length-1]).charCodeAt() < 48 || (str1[str1.length-1]).charCodeAt() > 57){
    valueRef.value = str1.substring(0,str1.length-1 );
    return;
  } 

 // t.replace(/,/g,'')
  let str = (valueRef.value).replace(/,/g,'');

  let value = +str;

  valueRef.value = value.toLocaleString();
}
```

[Working Codepen Demo Link](https://codepen.io/mukeshm280/pen/GRKyZVq)

Answer (score -3):

```js
function inputLimiter(e,allow) {
    var AllowableCharacters = '';

    if (allow == 'custom'){AllowableCharacters=' 1234567890.';}


    var k = document.all?parseInt(e.keyCode): parseInt(e.which);
    if (k!=13 && k!=8 && k!=0){
        if ((e.ctrlKey==false) && (e.altKey==false)) {
        return (AllowableCharacters.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(k))!=-1);
        } else {
        return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="NameCharacters" onkeypress="return inputLimiter(event,'custom')" value="" maxlength="4" /></p>
```

In Javascript. But this was as far as I got, will just leave this here for awhile, need to handle other stuffs.

Comment: Will try this later. Thx

Comment: Thanks for the example but its possible to add '...2' which breaks the pattern. Do you have an idea on how to use the same pattern as specified in the step variable on the input in a dynamic solution which can be applied on different inputs with different steps specified? Why do you link angularjs and jQuery? Couldn't find any code that are depending on them..

Comment: I link jQuery and angularjs because i have a bookmark that automatically includes them, as most of my works require them and it doesn't really cost any performance hit. It is possible to force a digit as the first digit, and limit the decimal to appear only once in this string. But it will cause the issue of allowing an input of 000. in this case.