# check telephone number format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use regular expression in JavaScript which limit number of phone in ten digit and the two first digit must begin with `06` or `07`.

- Example correct format: `0688342134`, `0721654709`;
- Example bad format: `0588342134`, `0421654709`.

```
var phoneno = /^\+?([0-9]{2})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
if (inputtxt.value.match(phoneno)) {
  return true;
} else {  
  alert("valid phone number must begin with 06 or 07 and have ten digit");
  return false;
}
```

It doesn't begin with `06` or `07`.
Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076985/format-number-in-an-html5-input-tag

Comment: If the phone has only numbers, you can use: `/^0[67]\d{8}$/`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function checkPhone(phone) {
  return (new RegExp(/^0[6-7][\d]{8}$/)).test(phone);
}

let phones = [
  '0678901234', // true: starting with '06' and 10-chars length
  '067890123', // false: starting with '06' but 9-chars length
  '06789012345', // false: starting with '06' but 11-chars length
  '0789012345', // true: starting with '07' and 10-chars length
  '0890123456' // false: 10-chars length but starting with '08'
];
phones.forEach(phone => {
  console.log(checkPhone(phone));
});
```

Comment: I thought no one answered the question! when I posted my answer noticed you already answered the question with an identical solution!

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
    <input type="tel" pattern="06|07\d{8}">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Answer (score 1):

this is what you want:

```
reg = /^0[67]\d{8}$/
```

- ^: # Assert position at the beginning of the string.
- 0[67]: means 0 followed by 6 or 7.
- d{8}: means 8 numbers
- $: # Assert position at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno) && (inputtxt.value.substring(0,2)=='06' || inputtxt.value.substring(0,2)=='07')) { return true; }
```

Comment: Good it's work fine, but i have another question how can i  allow only digit and not character in input of phone number

Comment: Also, it's recommended to explain how your code addresses/solves the OP's question. Code only answers are frowned upon. Adding info allows visitors to quickly zoom in on the important bits, is quicker to cognitively digest, and helps fire visitors learn, and apply knowledge to their own code. This then favors Q &A for knowledge, over "give me the code" as a service Q and A. It also keeps quality high for SO as a platform.

Comment: he wanted to check if the string started with 06 or 07, so I used substring(0,2) to determine if it started with 06 or 07.

Answer (score 0):

Update your regular expression to:

```js
var phoneno = /^\+?(0[67])\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
```

The part that matches the first two numbers changed from `([0-9]{2})`, which matches 2 of any number, to `(0[67])`, which matches a 0 followed by a 6 or 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var phoneno = /^\+?(0[67])\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/
```

Change

```
[0-9]{2}
```

To

```
0[67]
```

**Explanation**

`0` matches the digit zero.

`[67]` matches one occurrence of either 6 or 7.