# HTML5 input pattern not working in input type="number"

Tags: css, html

I used input pattern in `input type="text"` its working
its working code

```
<input name="name" required pattern=".{4,}" title="Please Enter Correct Name" type="text" />
```

But when I used input pattern in `input type="number"` its not working

```
<input name="number" required type="number" pattern=".{9,20}" title="Please Enter Your Number at least 9 Digit" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work with type="number". Check this out https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#do-not-apply

Comment: You should use JavaScript instead of pattern on number input.

Comment: ^^ and here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-(type=number) - point 4 under bookkeeping details.

Comment: By the way, `required="true"` is wrong; it should be either just `required` or `required="required"`. See [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-required).

Comment: @MrLister actually that is incorrect if you are supporting IE.  Older versions of Internet explorer only recognize `required="true"`. since all other browsers only need the required attribute to be present, `required=true` is the most universal version

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley I can't seem to reproduce that behaviour. Which versions of IE are we talking about?

Comment: @MrLister i think it's IE 6 - 9 if i remember correctly

Comment: the key being there isn't a browser I'm aware of that required="true" doesn't work for that `required` and `required=required` do

Comment: after further research I can't find where I got that info from.. but the point still stands that any html5 enabled browser will still recognize `required=true`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a pattern on an input\[type="number"\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411753/how-to-use-a-pattern-on-an-inputtype-number)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern)

> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. The pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset. Use the title attribute to describe the pattern to help the user. This attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text, search, tel, url, email, or password, otherwise it is ignored.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern attributes only works with `text`, `date`, `search`, `url`, `tel`, `email`, and `password` input types: [HTML5 input specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element). Scroll down a bit and you will see a table telling you which attributes can be used with the different input types.

You should use javascript to achieve what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern attribute works with the following input types: text, date, search, url, tel, email, and password. 
Therefore you can't use it with input number
You can check here

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input
- https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element