# How to place a HTML validation error when reached the maxlength="11"?

Tags: javascript, html

In order to create a survey form, I want to be able for my users to leave their telephone number. A telephone number in Holland will never be more than 10 digits. I want to place an HTML validation error if so.

Comment: You will find a lot of libraries that can help you with that if you do some research, for example, the first answer on Google gives me: https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js

Comment: You can do it using javascript. pleasea refer [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely do it by CSS, by simply checking the `:valid` or `:invalid` pseudo-states in combination with the `pattern` attribute that is applicable to a selected subset of `<input>` elements:

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}

.error-message {
  display: none;
}
input:invalid + .error-message {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="tel" pattern="\d{10}" />
  <span class="error-message">Please enter a 10-digit phone number</span>
</form>
```

The subset of `<input>` elements where pattern checking is enabled are [text, search, tel, url, email, or password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489268/395910).

However, a word of caution: you should **never** rely on the client (HTML or JS) as a single point of validation. You will still need to use server-side validation, because native form validation simply serves as an advisory, and JS-based validation can be easily bypassed if the user has access to the console and has a bit of JS know-how.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to keep the maxlength=10 in that case, the customer wont be allowed to enter more than 10 digits then.

Comment: Thank u for your help but i want a validation error. To make it clear..